# What does "Cockroach King" really signify?

Tags: meaning, prog-metal

From the song 'Cockroach King' by Haken.
Song ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQiF1NZMPEE
Lyrics ref: https://genius.com/Haken-cockroach-king-lyrics

The lyrics make it seem like 'Cockroach King' is some character who has fooled the protagonist of the album "The Mountain". But, I am still wondering about the choice of the wording. Why was that "Con" named as "Cockroach King"? Is there any special meaning to it?